# Confused by behavior of Django 1.5 with auth password change on the template name location

Tags: django, django-templates

I am fairly new to Django, and I am confused by a behavior and I am scratching my head to understand why it's not working the way I would expect.

I am customizing my template for the password change (`password_change_form.html`) and I put it in my application template directory under `registration`.

I am using **django-registration**. In my `settings.py` in INSTALLED_APPS I have the default apps in the default order (`'django.contrib.auth'` etc...), my app, and `registration`. The admin is enabled.
I know Django looks for the templates in the order set in the INSTALLED_APPS variable.

In my project urls.py I have

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'', include('website.urls', namespace="website")),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

In my application urls.py I have

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
   url(r'^accounts/profile/password/change/$', 
       'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', 
       {'template_name': 'registration/password_change_form.html'}, 
       name='edit_password'),
)
```

My **confusion** is that if I leave the `template_name` set to `'registration/password_change_form.html'` Django will display the default Admin form for password change **not** my custom template.

I created a directory under my app templates called `auth` and I copied my template at this location.
Now if I change the `template_name` to `'auth/password_change_form.html'` Django will show my template!

I am confused because Django is not following *my instruction* to use my template at the location `registration` but it will if it's at location `auth`.

Can somebody explain to me what's happening under the hood of Django 1.5 and why it will only use my template only if it's in the directory it likes?!

Comment: Seems the culprit would be the order in the INSTALLED_APPS and to have the `'django.contrib.admin'` line after my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the problem is that your first instruction is the default instruction - the same one that pulls the `password_change_form.html` in installed app order. IF you were to examine the default value for the `template_name` field, it would be exactly what you are setting it to. Just because you set the value yourself instead of letting it take the default value - it still processes it the same way. It looks in the order of installed_apps for a template directory with a registration subdirectory, and a password_change_form.html file. So regardless, unless you give it a name that **DOES NOT EXIST** in the default django auth templates - it won't go where you want (unless you place your app before the auth app in settings). Now, if you want to keep your folder structure the same, just change the name of the file and pass in the correct name to the `template_name` field.